# using php with J2me Post or Get

Tags: php, java-me

a j2me application i created using both POST and GET can read any length of data from the ServerSide(php).the mobile waits in a thread until all the data is sent from the Server. however when i send the data from Mobile to ServerSide the Server cant wait for the mobile to send all its contents. am receiving an empty String at the serverSide, when the data sent from the Mobile is too long. am expecting that the serverSide should either contain all or half of the String sent by mobile.

how can i make Server to wait for all the content to arrive?

Answer (score 0):

It's totally dependent on your web server's configuration. Since all the incoming data is sent to the server in the request headers — you should increase request timeouts. For example, in nginx it's made with `client_header_timeout` and `client_body_timeout` [configuration parameters](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html).

Comment: @Smotesko i cant understand what makes the server kill the connection when i send a long string using j2me as the client, if i paste the same string on a browser it takes some time but the string is sent successfully. so what makes the server ignore the string i send using J2me if its Long because no error is returned at all as indicated from this configurations http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html

Comment: I have another idea: try to log the messages you are sending from J2ME. It might be two carriage return symbols in the middle of message which is interpreted as the end of message by server.

Comment: Also, if you are sending a message from a real mobile phone via GPRS connection, it can be issue with timeouts. But if this behaviour is seen when running MIDlet in the emulator — it's not an issue.

Comment: And one more thought: enable very detailed logging in the webserver config and read the log.

Comment: @Smotesko here is some of the requests am sending with post and get. for get 414 error is returned but for POST nothing is returned and the server fails to receive the string

Comment: I think that reading the log file at maximum verbosity will give you the answer.